# VaporMySQL Provider

Tags: vapor

```
import Vapor
import VaporMySQL

let mysql = try VaporMySQL.Provider(host: "localhost", user: "username", password: "secret", database: "coffeeLedger")
```

What is the difference between

```
let drop = Droplet(preparations: [CoffeeLedger.self], providers: [VaporMySQL.Provider.self])
```

and....

```
let drop = Droplet(preparations: [CoffeeLedger.self], providers: [mysql])
```

I get a `Cannot convert value of type 'Provider' to expected element type 'Provider.Type'` error

Answer (score 1):

`providers` was renamed to `initializedProviders` in Vapor 0.16 to make room for `ConfigInitializable` provider support.

Basically, now you can just pass the `Type` of the provider and it will attempt to initialize from the configuration files in the `Config/` folder.

This style of initialization helps remove magic numbers and strings from the source code, like the host and password.

If you want to keep initializing the provider normally, just use `initializedProvider:`